# How do I have RabbitMQ redeliver unacknowledged messages?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm following the following tutorial to the letter:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html.

I start the RabbitMQ server as such:

```
docker pull rabbitmq
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit-host --name my-rabbit -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3
```

From the tutorial:

> Using this code we can be sure that even if you kill a worker using
>   CTRL+C while it was processing a message, nothing will be lost. Soon
>   after the worker dies all unacknowledged messages will be redelivered.

I spawn two consumers, and when I CTRL+C one of them, the other running one does *not* receive the messages that were originally destined to the former consumer. How do I get the messages to be redelivered after CTRL+C'ing out of one of the consumers?

Edit: I'm now installing RabbitMQ via 'brew', but I'm still seeing the same issue.

```
brew update
brew install rabbitmq
/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server &
```

Comment: From what you describe, it should work out-of-the-box. Did you put a sleep instead of the `doWork` stuff and stop the consumer during the sleep? (obviously, once the message is "basicAcked", it won't be delivered again to any consumer).Are you sure the other consumer is actually consuming?

Comment: Correct - I put a sleep just before ack'ing. I CTRL+C during the sleep. I'm printing the message in the consumer's handleDelivery() callback, but it's never getting through.

Comment: If you have both consumers consuming, do they receive messages evenly or is it always the same that receives the messages? If it's always the same consumer, it could be a sign that the second consumer is not properly configured (not bound correctly to the queue for instance). To be even more confident, put a some messages in the queue and ensure they both consume concurrently.

Also, use `rabbitmq:3-management` docker image (+ forward 15672 and open it your browser, username is `guest` and password is `guest`) to find out what is actually happening to the message in the queue.

Comment: The consumers receive the messages in round-robin style. For some reason, when I install via Docker, the mgmt plugin doesn't see any active connections or queues. I went ahead and installed via 'brew' instead, and now the mgmt plugin page sees the activity. However, the messages still aren't being redelivered after missing the ack from the CTRL+C.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to put sleep or anything like that in the consumer code. On the link you provided, search for paragraph starting with *Manual message acknowledgments* and look at the code there. The key thing is not to acknowledge the message. If you have autoACK flag set to true, then you can call anything you want, the message is acknowledged as soon as it is received. So simply don't set that flag, and also for testing you could comment out the line `channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);` in order not to do manual ACK either. So when the consumer exits, the message will still be in the queue.

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't seem to work. Let me know if you'd like to see the code.

Comment: @Phillip sure, add your code to the question please

Answer (score 0):

Strange, RabbitMQ works for me out of the box.

**Step 1**, I started RabbitMQ:

```
$ docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit-host --name my-rabbit -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                   NAMES
e0c3257b8b49        rabbitmq:3          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp   my-rabbit
```

**Step 2**, I published a message (By the way, I tried with Node.js. See Appendix below for source code):

```
$ node src/producer.js
Publisher:  TODO 1st
```

**Step 3**, I started two consumers one after another (my consumer is designed, for the testing purpose, not to acknowledge, so RabbitMQ will never dequeue a message).

Consumer 1 will receive the message, while consumer 2 won't.

Consumer 1:

```
$ node src/consumer.js 
Consumer:  TODO 1st
```

Consumer 2:

```
$ node src/consumer.js
```

**Step 4**, when I stop consumer 1 by 'Ctrl + c', Consumer 2 will immediately receive the message from RabbitMQ:

Consumer 2:

```
$ node src/consumer.js 
Consumer:  TODO 1st
```

**Conclusion**: Basically, when setting up a consumer, we need to tell RabbitMQ not to dequeue the message until its acknowledgement has been received from the consumer. As a result, if consumer 1 is stopped for any reason before it has a chance to acknowledge the message, RabbitMQ will redeliver the message to consumer 2.

### Appendix

src/producer.js

```
var q = 'tasks'

function bail (err) {
  console.error(err)
  process.exit(1)
}

// Publisher
function publisher (conn) {
  conn.createChannel(onOpen)
  function onOpen (err, ch) {
    if (err != null) bail(err)
    ch.assertQueue(q)
    const msg = 'TODO 1st'
    ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from(msg), { persistent: true })
    console.log('Publisher: ', msg)
  }
}

require('amqplib/callback_api')
  .connect('amqp://guest:guest@localhost', function (err, conn) {
    if (err != null) bail(err)
    publisher(conn)
  })
```

src/consumer.js

```
var q = 'tasks'

function bail (err) {
  console.error(err)
  process.exit(1)
}

// Consumer
function consumer (conn) {
  conn.createChannel(onOpen)
  function onOpen (err, ch) {
    if (err != null) bail(err)
    ch.assertQueue(q)
    ch.consume(q, function (msg) {
      if (msg !== null) {
        console.log('Consumer: ', msg.content.toString())
        // Commented out the line below, so RabbitMQ never dequeues a message
        // ch.ack(msg)
      }
    }, { noAck: false })
  }
}

require('amqplib/callback_api')
  .connect('amqp://guest:guest@localhost', function (err, conn) {
    if (err != null) bail(err)
    consumer(conn)
  })
```